# CSS target element 2 on 1:hover and element 1 on 2:hover

Tags: css, hover, reverse, targeting

I "need" to target the *other* sibling of each of two elements (actually children of siblings) on :hover. I can get the code block below to work, but I cannot get it to work in the reverse. I understand there is no designated method of targeting like this: ".element2:hover + .element1", but I did find this ([Is there a "previous sibling" CSS selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/is-there-a-previous-sibling-css-selector)) which had some creative solutions including RTL and some tricky :nth-child ideas. However, I still couldn't see a way to go BOTH ways, but rather just switching directions (I need both).

MARKUP:

```
<div class="element1">Element 1</div>
<div class="element2">
    <p class="child">
        <span class="grandchild">Element 2</span>
    </p>
    <p class="child2"></p>
</div>
<div class="element3">Element 3</div>
```

CSS:

```
.element1:hover + .element2 .child .grandchild { background-color: red; }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/macwise/6u3nj18m/

EDIT: I added a third root child element (.element3) to reflect the real-world case I'm working with.

Update: perhaps my language of "previous sibling" was vague and therefore misconstrued as "parent" ([Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861)).  Parent targeting would probably offer a satisfactory solution too, but I am technically needing to target "one sibling of a parent which comes before another sibling of that same parent." It's simpler than it sounds. :) Hope that clears things up.

Comment: Thanks Trix! I updated to clarify that while that case could offer a solution, it is not the same issue.

Comment: That thread discusses the either/or scenario.  I am looking for the "cake and eat it" scenario, or the best of both worlds.  As explained in my post, that thread only wants to reverse the order so `.element2` triggers `.element1`.  I need that AND `.element1` to trigger `.element2`, AND I need it to trigger different styles for each element. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

you could catch hover from parent and trigger it once you hover a child.

then apply bg to all divs, but the one hovered :

```css
body div {
    pointer-events: auto;
}
body {
    pointer-events: none;
}
body:hover div {
    background: red;
}
body:hover div:hover {
    background: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="element1">Element 1</div>
<div class="element2">
  <p class="child">
    <span class="grandchild">Element 2</span>
  </p>
  <p class="child2"></p>
</div>
```

**But, this is for the fun only, you should use JavaScript for this.**

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Hmmm...I have a third element (updated the post to reflect that), but perhaps your answer combined with a :not() pseudo-element to always exclude the third non-related child might work?

Comment: I got this far: https://jsfiddle.net/macwise/5vc698fw/2/

But I need to have a different declaration on each child (font color in one, background in the other)

Comment: Bah.  Alas, element three contains links, too. :( I'm quickly learning how not to ask a good SO question.